# Grouped chart in python (matplotlib.pyplot)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following table as a result of a SQL query:

```
SYS|LOCKED|UNLOCKED|
 A |   2  |  3     |
 B |   1  |  2     |
 C |   4  |  1     |
```

This is the result of the SQL query that is put into pandas dataframe and I would like to turn it into the grouped chart where X = SYS and Y = first column with numbers of LOCKED and the second column with UNLOCKED items.
This is the code so far, but it misses the plot code. Any ideas?

```
import pyodbc
import os
import sys
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open('serv1.txt', 'r') as servfile:
    serv = servfile.read()

with open('datab1.txt', 'r') as databfile:
    datab = databfile.read()

print(serv)
print(datab)
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('Trusted_Connection=yes', driver = '{ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}',server = serv, database = datab)
print(cnxn)
SQL_Query = pd.read_sql_query("""select SYS,
                                   sum(case when LOCK_STAT = 'Locked' then 1 else 0 end) as LOCKED,
                                   sum(case when LOCK_STAT = 'Unlocked' then 1 else 0 end) as UNLOCKED
                                from dbo.USR_02_ALL_RAW
                                group by SYS;""")
df = pd.DataFrame(SQL_Query, columns=['SYS', 'LOCKED','UNLOCKED'])
```

From here on is where I am not sure about the code. The SQL query creates the table as above, but I am not sure how to put into into grouped chart where Y has two bars for each group (SYS on X axis).

Any ideas?

Comment: This example could be helpful https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/94c8e2584eba3bad7c42ede8680da714da73dbc3/examples/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `set_index` and `pd.DataFrame.plot.bar`

MCVE:

Where df,

```
   SYS  LOCKED  UNLOCKED
0   A        2         3
1   B        1         2
2   C        4         1
```

Then,

```
df.set_index('SYS').plot.bar()
```

Output:

[image]